# Split a string between pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
a="\r\nOk\r\n\r\nThanks\r\n"

I want to split string so i will get:

array[0]="Ok"
array[1]="Thanks"
```

What i've tried:

```
array=re.split('\r\n',a)
```

Which resulted in a complicated list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need `regex` just use `str.split()` :

```
>>> a="\r\nOk\r\n\r\nThanks\r\n"
>>> a.split()
['Ok', 'Thanks']
```

[**str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) :
If sep is not specified or is `None` runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns []

Comment: Thanks all ! all the answers helped !

Answer (score 3):

Use `|` to separate the delimiters in the expression, and just filter out empty strings as you go:

```
>>> [s for s in re.split(r'\r|\n', a) if s]
['Ok', 'Thanks']
```

Comment: Alternatively, there's [os.linesep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep) for portability.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way. There is no need of mentioning any number of `\n\r` or any `spaces` for stripping a string. These are automatically stripped.

```
>>> a="\r\nOk\r\n\r\nThanks\r\n"
>>> a.strip().split()
['Ok', 'Thanks']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "\r\nOk\r\n\r\nThanks\r\n"
array = a.split("\r\n")
array = [item for item in array if item]
```

Update: The answer above by Kasra is simpler and therefore preferable.

Comment: What exactly does this `[item for item in array if item]`?

Comment: It goes through all the items in array and creates a new array with only the ones that aren't equal to "".

Comment: `a.split()` is all that is needed

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's true. Kasra gave that answer and I upvoted it.